# How to create a toolbar on the taskbar in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar, taskbar, windows-explorer

I want to create a taskbar toolbar from my WPF application in c#. Once created, I want to assign it a folder. The Toolbar will then show the contents of the file folder.

Screenshot of what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for making a shell alteration like that (I believe this is mentioned on Raymond Chen's blog, but I don't have the link, sorry). This is because Microsoft believes the user should be in control of the taskbar, not applications.

Comment: Too bad, I'll have to just pin them as large icons or have the user create a taskbar. Seeing as my app is for more advanced users this is more of an annoyance than a real problem.